# Using たら, how do I say "would have" instead of "would"

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I'm struggling to understand how I can change the tense of conditional sentences.

For example, if I want to say "If I were him, I wouldn't say such things" I presume I would say "もし私が彼だったらあんなことは言わない". But if I want to say "If I were him, I wouldn't have said such things" should I say "もし私が彼だったらあんなことは言わなかった" ?

Comment: You probably want 「私だったら」 or 「私なら」 instead of the wordy 「もし私が彼だったら」

Answer (score 7):

「あんなことは言{い}わなかった」 would be quite acceptable in non-formal speech.  It would easily be understood to mean "I would not have said ~~" by native speakers ***if used in the right context***.

You should, however, be at least aware that ***grammatically speaking***, 「言わなかった」 is only in the simple past tense.

More formally and/or academically, you can say:

> 「言わなかった**であろう**」 and its shorter version is:
>
> 「言わなかった**だろう**」

It is also very natural and common to say:

> 「言わなかったと思{おも}う/思います」

Comment: If anyone has a reference to a grammar blog/lesson/dictionary that talks about these forms, could you share a link? I didn't see these examples in my textbook, so would like to find a source to learn this type of grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding (JLPT N2), your suggested sentence "もし私が彼だったらあんなことは言わなかった" is correct.

Although in this case, I would agree with the comment on your OP above (which seems to no longer be there, maybe it was deleted) to use なら instead, unless there's a particular reason you want to use たら.